# UICollectionView from portrait to landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView in my project. I started to do all the stuff programmatically(in swift).
this is my code which initiate and add the collectionView to the screen:

```
var collectionView: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: COLLECTION_VIEW_DISTANCE_TOP, left: COLLECTION_VIEW_DISTANCE_LEFT, bottom: COLLECTION_VIEW_DISTANCE_BOTTOM, right: COLLECTION_VIEW_DISTANCE_RIGHT)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 120)

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
}
```

The variables with all-capital letters are constant which I created before.

Everything is going alright, except when I switch from portrait to landscape, the number of items in each row doesn't change, although when switching to landscape it should be more items in the row than before.

I've tried to override this function:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    collectionView.frame = self.view.frame
}
```

It worked, but when rotating the iPhone it takes about a half second to fill the rows(It does the job slowly, in an ugly way).

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple deprecated the method of willRotateMethod in iOS 8 SDK. so what you write code in didRotateMethod method that code you will write in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so your problem will be solved.

Comment: There is no such that method.
I tried overriding this method:
    override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    
    }
but it didn't work for me.